# Why is this null check in the getter causing the value to be null in the controller?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a controller defined as:

```
public void saveCustomer(@Valid @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer) {
    // persist
}
```

and a getter in Customer:

```
public List<ContactInfo> getContactInfo() {
    if(contactInfo != null) {
        return contactInfo;
    }
    else {
        return new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();
    }
}
```

If I hit the controller with a HTML form then the contact info is null. **But**, if I change the getter to

```
public List<ContactInfo> getContactInfo() {
    return contactInfo;
}
```

then the contact info is bound and persisted correctly.  I am really confused as to why this is happening.

I have checked in Chrome and the contact info is definitely in the request params as:

```
contactInfo[0].alias:test
contactInfo[0].email:test@test.com
```

Comment: Are there multiple threads involved?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I haven't explicitly set up multithreading but I am not sure what Spring is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don’t make `contactInfo` non-`null`, it’ll just keep making a new `ArrayList`:

```
public List<ContactInfo> getContactInfo() {
    if(contactInfo == null) {
        contactInfo = new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();
    }

    return contactInfo;
}
```

Comment: When I said "the contact info seems to get lost" I really meant that it is null in the controller.  Is something happening with the `@ModelAttribute` binding?  I just don't understand why the null check would prevent the binding.

Comment: So this works, though I am unsure why.  When the request hits the controller and the data binding happens for `Customer`, shouldn't Spring just be calling setters to inflate the object?  There must be something going on that I don't understand.

Comment: @mattblang: I’m not familiar with Spring’s internals, or java at all, but I it makes sense for a list to be retrieved once and then added to instead of repeatedly retrieved and replaced. Much more efficient.